# Output sql query to a variable then create a new query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to output the query results from one table and using that same variable as a 'like' in another table. 
The first part of the query is supposed to get me everything *. The variable (or array) will be used in the second part of the query as part of 'like'.

This is what I have:

```
DECLARE @UpnPref nvarchar(100), @WC nvarchar(10)
Set @UpnPref = 0
Set @WC = '*'

Select @upnpref = UpnPrefix from dbo.ADUsers where UPNPrefix = @WC

print @upnpref  <-- returns a 0

Select * from dbo.UserMailbox where LinkedAccount like '%' + @UpnPref +'%'
```

Comment: Try if SELECT UpnPrefix FROM dbo.ADUsers WHERE UPNPrefix = '*' returns anything, because that's what you're trying to assign to @UpnPref

Comment: It returns 0, nothing else.

Comment: So there you go... But your select statement doesn't make any sense. Its unclear what you're trying to do

Comment: What I need to do is pass a wildcard, but how?

Comment: There are no wildcards in SQL Server per se. UPNPref like '%xyz%' will match any value of UPNPref that includes 'xyz'.

Comment: Dimitri - the query 'select * from dbo.Adusers' returns more than 100k records.

Comment: when I mean wildcard, I'm referring to * (everything)

Comment: let me put it into psuedo code: var = sql query - give me everything in table A. Next, for each record in the var, give me the name associated with it in table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is select everything from dbo.UserMailbox that has LinkedAccount matching UpnPrefix of every record in dbo.ADUsers, you can do it so:

```
SELECT U.* 
FROM dbo.UserMailbox U
    INNER JOIN dbo.ADUsers A ON U.LinkedAccount = A.UpnPrefix
```

Comment: You could mark it as Accepted Answer if this solves the issue